# Error to import module in python using TOS

Tags: python, module, talend

Im currently trying to run a spark job where the job will use a module that is imported from a python script. This job works when I run it in terminal as I run the spark job in the same directory where the python script (for library) is stored.

However, when I tried to run the spark job in TOS, it returns this error:

```
from filename import full_ingestion 
ImportError: No module named filename
```

I assumed that the talend cant found the library, so I used tLibraryLoad to import the new library to TOS and set it up as below:

[image]

In tLibraryLoad_1 :

1. basic setting : filename.py (this is the library script I wrote in python)
2. advanced setting : import full_ingestion (full_ingestion is a function in filename.py)

In tSystem component:
-> In spark job script , put import full_ingestion

However, I received this error.

[image]

Am i doing a correct way to import a library created in python script to the spark job in TOS?

Comment: tLibraryLoad is used to import .jar files. The import statement from the advanced settings is in Java. It's usually better to import your external .jar files through importing modules (Window -> Show View -> Modules). In your case, have you checked if the filename.py is included in the Python classpath?

Comment: Hi Adrian, yes thats correct i cant used tLibraryLoad. Question, to use classpath I set it up in Windows > Preference > Java > Buildpath > Classpath Variables (and upload filename.py file as a new classpath variable). but how should I use that classpath in talend. cannot find a good reference on this.

Comment: Have you tried having to have your cmd command to point to the full filepath? ie. python my/file/path/filename.py. In case that doesn't work try to add .py like "from filename.py import .." The problem seems to be something with the environmental variables. If your file is located on the same filesystem as Talend it should be able to execute it since according to the error it does find python itself.